# PKG Failed to make Bytecode

Tags: javascript

I am getting this warning when I try and run .. pkg index.js -t macOS

node v17.3.1
pkg@5.5.2

> Warning Failed to make bytecode node17-arm64 for file /snapshot/______/index.js

was hoping anyone could help,

I have also tried to use -b and got

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/fy/c5tgsjcj63q73kfvg_dd53fh0000gn/T/pkg.d5ef9dd92b18360a4ff95824/node/out/Release/node

thank you

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75019478/10030693

Answer (score 3):

I used `@vercel/ncc` to generate one index.js file and then use `pkg` on the generated `index.js` file.

My `package.json` `scripts` is like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js",
    "build": "ncc build  -o build/lib ./src/index.js && pkg --target node16-win-x64 -o build/MY-API.exe ./build/lib/index.js"
  },
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks.
Is there a way to use npx with ncc?

Comment: @SovatthaSok of course. Just do `npx ncc ...`

Answer (score 2):

My Script was written in ES6, I ran it threw Babel and then tried again and it worked perfectly!!

Comment: Hi, Can you provide the commands used with babel and configs? I have similar issues.

Comment: Hey sorry for late reply. I can't even remember what project this was from .. but im pretty sure I ran the code threw https://babeljs.io s website and just copy and pasted the results! ..

I know it was kinda a hack job.. but it worked for me!