# NodeJS: pkg failes to create exe file after installing d3.js package

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I created a rather simple NodeJS + express app. Until now I used *pkg 5.7.0* to make an EXE package like this:

```
pkg package.json --compress GZip --targets node10-win-x64 --out-dir package
```

As soon as I add D3 (npm install d3) to my project pkg stops creating EXE files with following errors. Notice, I did not even added anything from D3 to my project code yet. I just installed the package (for now) and it already broke.

**Is it possible to fix this somehow?** I have no babel or webpack installed and would prefer not to do it for this small project.

```
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-array\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-axis\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-brush\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-chord\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-color\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-contour\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-delaunay\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-dispatch\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-drag\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-dsv\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-ease\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-fetch\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-force\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-format\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-geo\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-hierarchy\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-interpolate\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-path\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-polygon\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-quadtree\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-random\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-scale\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-scale-chromatic\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-selection\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-shape\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-time\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-time-format\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-timer\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-zoom\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\internmap\src\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\delaunator\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\interrupt.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\selection\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\selection\interrupt.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\selection\transition.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\attr.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\attrTween.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\delay.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\duration.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\ease.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\easeVarying.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\end.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\filter.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\interpolate.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\merge.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\on.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\remove.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\schedule.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\select.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\selectAll.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\selection.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\style.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\styleTween.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\text.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\textTween.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\transition.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\d3-transition\src\transition\tween.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file C:\snapshot\BAP-App\node_modules\robust-predicates\index.js
```

my dependencies in package.json are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "d3": "^7.6.1",
    "detect-file-encoding-and-language": "^2.2.2",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "fast-csv": "^4.3.6",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.6.3",
    "legacy-encoding": "^3.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multimap": "^1.1.0",
    "pkg": "^5.7.0",
    "sprintf-js": "^1.1.2",
    "tree-model": "^1.0.7"
  },
```

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75019478/10030693